# Prove that if $T_n \rightarrow T$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ then $T_n x_n \rightarrow T x$

Tags: functional-analysis, strong-convergence

$X$ - Banach space and $T_n$ bounded linear operators that is strongly convergent to $T$ as well as $x_n$ is strongly convergent to $x$.

How to prove that $T_n x_n$ is strongly convergent to $Tx$?

I kinda understand that we can prove the case where $T_n x$ is strongly convergent to $Tx$

it is like this $\left\|T x-T_{n} x\right\| \leq\left\|T-T_{n}\right\|\|x\|<\epsilon\|x\|$ ...

But how to proof statement in my case I am not sure. But intuitively it is seems to me obvious thing.

Comment: By strongly converge do you mean $T_nx \to Tx$ for all $x$ or $\| T_n - T\| \to 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
| T_n x_n - Tx | 
&= |T_n x_n - T_n x + T_n x - T x| \\
&\leq |T_n x_n - T_n x| + |T_n x - T x| \\
&= |T_n (x_n - x)| + |T_n x - T x|
\end{align}
$$

Do you know how to control $T_n x_n \to T_n x$ and $T_n x \to T_x$ separately? It will be helpful to remember that $T_n$ is bounded, and thus continuous.

Once you do this, you'll notice it doesn't *quite* work, since our bound for $|T_n x_n - T_n x|$ depends on $n$ (do you see why?). We can fix this, though, by using the fact that for large $n$, $T_n \approx T$. Can you modify the above proof, say by using the inequality (which holds for all vectors $y$)

$$|T_n y| \leq \lVert T_n \rVert \lVert y \rVert$$

and then controlling $\lVert T_n \rVert$ using (**Edit:** Thanks to Nate Eldredge for the correction) the uniform boundedness principle? If you happen to know that a sequence of operators which converge pointwise are bounded in norm, you can also use that directly.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Note you can't directly control $\|T_n\|$ in terms of $\|T\|$ under these assumptions, but you can control it using the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @NateEldredge -- Would you mind elaborating? I thought we had $\lVert T_n - T \rVert \to 0$, which lets us directly control $\lVert T_n \rVert$. I haven't seen "strongly convergent" applied to operators before, so I took the definition that made the proof easier, haha. Does it mean some kind of pointwise convergence?

Comment: Yes, it's pointwise convergence.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology

Comment: @NateEldredge the OP seems to be using "stongly convergent" to mean norm convergent (they wrote $T_n x $ is strongly convergent to $Tx$). We also have a tag [tag:strong-convergence] which is just the usual convergence in norm. Would the norm "strong convergence" be used somewhere in the world?

Comment: @ArcticChar: My experience is that when one speaks of a sequence of *vectors* converging strongly, it means in norm.  When one speaks of a sequence of *operators* converging strongly, it means in the strong operator topology, i.e. for every $x$ we have $T_n x \to Tx$ strongly.  So that is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: I agree with that. I think this strong-convergence tag should probably not exist at all, or else it should be renamed to norm-convergence or convergence-in-norm, for example. This post could I suppose be better tagged as strong-operator-topology, but that tag doesn't exist. There may simply be too many topologies in functional analysis to make it worth giving each one a tag.

Comment: @NateEldredge Does the same result hold when we only know that $T_n \rightarrow T$ strongly, and $x_n \rightarrow x$, but we do not suppose that $T_n$ is bounded and that their domain is Banach space?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric: In general, practically nothing useful can be said about unbounded operators which are not closable, which would be the case for your example.  For instance, fix a Hamel basis $\{u_i\}$ of unit vectors in your infinite-dimensional Banach space, and pick out a countable set $\{u_{i_n} : n = 1,2\,\dots\}$.  Let $T_n$ be the unique linear operator which maps $u_{i_n}$ to $n^2 u_{i_n}$ and maps all other $u_i$ to $0$.  Let $x_n = \frac{1}{n} u_{i_n}$.  Then $T_n \to 0$ pointwise, $x_n \to 0$ in norm,, but $T_n x_n$ diverges.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm trying to apply this idea on a concrete Banach space, e.g.,$\ell^\infty$. However, I'm having issues proving it as the infinity norm prevents $T_n$ from converging to zero operator. Same happens with $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ for $1 \le p \lt \infty$ in their norms. Is it possible to form such a sequence of operators $T_n$ that they converge to the zero operator in these spaces? Do I need a more complex Banach space, perhaps?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric: This will work in any infinite-dimensional Banach space.  But it is impossible to construct a Hamel basis "concretely" (one has to invoke Zorn's lemma to prove that a Hamel basis exists), and likewise, it is also impossible to "concretely" define an unbounded operator whose domain is the entire Banach space.  So you have to give up on having a "concrete" counterexample.

Comment: @NemanjaBeric: But in the example I gave above, the operators $T_n$ do, by their very definition, converge strongly to the zero operator, and the infinity norm is not any obstruction to that. What makes you think that it is?    Indeed, you can even let the $u_{i_n}$ be the "usual basis" of indicators in $\ell^\infty$ - it's just that the uncountably many vectors $u_i$ needed to complete them to a  Hamel basis will be a weird pathological set.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you.I'm having some examples of exams for functional analysis course and I found this problem there. It's also in lectures left for exercise to prove that "If the sequence of operators $T_n$ converges strongly / pointwise to operator $T$ and sequence $x_n$ converges to element $x$, then $T_n x_n$ converges to $Tx$". It seems all fine, except it's impossible for me to prove the sequence $T_n$ is bounded and the book gives a hint to proving it via "principle of resonance" – whatever that is. It's my first functional analysis course, but the claim can't be both true and false.

Comment: @NateEldredge I searched it online and "principle of resonance" seems only to be something in physics. I'll try remembering your counter example, but there's a chance it won't be accepted on my exam - if I get to prove it. Anyways, thank you once again.

Comment: I would bet that your lecturer intended to assume that the operators $T_n$ are bounded, and either accidentally left it out, stated it somewhere else, or assumed it would be obvious from context.  If you're not sure, I'd suggest asking them if that's what they meant.  The claim is definitely not true without some such assumption.